# Como puedo acceder a los datos de una Collección php laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

tengo esta colección de datos, de una tabla que se llama "Actividades", esa tabla esta relacionada de muchos a muchos con otra tabla llamada "Estrategias".

Mi colección de datos tiene 3 actividades que comparten una estrategia.

entonces mi problema es como puedo mostrar en el html el atributo "descripcion" de la estrategia que está en las tres actividades.

en la imagen se ve la colección de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Esto es lo que tengo en el controllador

```
$actividades = Actividad::orderby('id', 'ASC')->with('estrategias')->where('evidencia_id', $evidenciaid)->get();
        dd($actividades);
```

*Esto es lo que he intentado hacer en el html

```
@foreach($actividades as $actividad)
    <div>
    {{$actividad->estrategias->descripcion}}}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Quita el estrategias que esta en el blade es decir {{$estrategias->descripcion}} quedará así

Comment: @LuisMorales hola, si lo quito no muestra nada, porque la descripción no hace parte de la actividad, si no de la estrategia que esta relacionada con la actividad.

Comment: Si, lo acabo de ver. En la imagen de colecion de datos despliega relación y valida que no tengas un valor null, si es así ahí es donde estará el problema.

Comment: ya que estrategias es otra colección, tendrías que agregar otro loop anidado dentro del que ya tienes. `@foreach($actividad->estrategias as $estrategia) {{ $estrategia->descripcion }} @endforeach`